# GWT SafeHtmlBuilder how to insert html code in a div

Tags: html, templates, gwt

I don't know if I'm trying to do something against the very nature of SafeHtmlBuilder. The thing is that I'd like to put html code (for instance, an < a > tag) in a div and make it safe. So here is my code:

```
SafeHtmlBuilder builder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();

builder.append(TEMPLATES.diagramHeader(
    BasicConstants.diagramHeaderId + "description", 
    newBox.getDescription());

newDiv.setInnerHTML(builder.toSafeHtml().asString());
```

And my template:

```
@Template("<div id=\"{0}\">{1}</div>") /* Description */
SafeHtml diagramHeader(String idDesc, String description);
```

When getDescription() returns a string with html code (e.g., an < a > tag) and the contents of newDiv are rendered, I don't see the hyperlink, what I see is the HTML CODE of the hyperlink.

I would like to see the hyperlink, how can I do this? (I am willing to sacrifice HTML's safety for the cause).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `description` argument to the template can contain markup, then it should be of type `SafeHtml`.

You'd then use [`SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(newBox.getDescription())`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlUtils.html#fromTrustedString%28java.lang.String%29), as you're trusting `newBox.getDescription()` to be *safe*.

---

As a side note, I don't understand why:

1. you use a `SafeHtmlBuilder` to `append()` only once
2. you use `setInnerHTML` instead of `setInnerSafeHtml` (maybe you're not using GWT 2.5?)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Regarding your question 1, the template structure I'm using is much more complex than what I pasted here (there are like 6 divs). That's why I'm using SafeHtmlBuilder... Does that answer your question? 

Regarding your question 2) ups, I'm still using GWT 2.4, thanks for the tipp! So, is there any way to see the hyperlink USING a SafeHTMLBuilder??

Comment: See first half of the answer. Doesn't that answer your question?