# how to apply html to SuggestList popup

Tags: gwt

How can I apply html to SuggestList popup in Gwt?
I want to apply html table in suggest list popup.

eg:

```
private SuggestOracle getSuggest() {
    oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();

    oracle.add("<table border=1><tr><td>hussain</td></tr><td>hussain1</td></table>");
    oracle.add("<table border=1><tr><td>taher</td></tr><td>taher1</td></table>");
    oracle.add("<table border=1><tr><td>hussain22</td></tr><td>hussain2</td></table>");

    return oracle;

}
```

The popup should show table with 2 column but it is taking html as text
Thanks
Husein

Answer (score 0):

Override [MultiWordSuggestOracle#isDisplayStringHTML()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MultiWordSuggestOracle.html#isDisplayStringHTML%28%29).

> Should SuggestOracle.Suggestion display strings be treated as HTML? If true, this all suggestions' display strings will be interpreted as HTML, otherwise as text.

```
MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle(){
     @Override
     public boolean isDisplayStringHTML(){
         return true;
     }
};
```

**Note:** Each suggestion has a display string and a replacement string.

For more info have a look at [SuggestOracle.Suggestion](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestOracle.Suggestion.html)

---

--EDIT--

For more info have a look at [MultiWordSuggestOracle and HTML display](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/KSqieEH-oHI)

complete sample code:

```
MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle() {
    @Override
    public boolean isDisplayStringHTML() {
        return true;
    }
};

Collection<Suggestion> suggestionList = new ArrayList<Suggestion>();
suggestionList.add(new MultiWordSuggestOracle.MultiWordSuggestion("hussain",
        "<table border='1'><tr><td>hussain</td></tr></table>"));
suggestionList.add(new MultiWordSuggestOracle.MultiWordSuggestion("taher1",
        "<table border='1'><tr><td>taher1</td></tr></table>"));
suggestionList.add(new MultiWordSuggestOracle.MultiWordSuggestion("hussain2",
        "<table border='1'><tr><td>hussain2</td></tr></table>"));

oracle.setDefaultSuggestions(suggestionList);
```

Comment: Please have a look at [GWT SafeHtmlBuilder how to insert html code in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119861/gwt-safehtmlbuilder-how-to-insert-html-code-in-a-div)

Comment: Thanks Braj for your responce Can you please show me the complete example

Comment: I am working on it. Meanwhile you can try it. `Each suggestion has a display string and a replacement string.` Follow the link as i have posted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Braj. The only problem now is on entering text in SuggestBox the matching Suggestions are the poping up

Comment: Follow the link to look it more. Right now I am busy. I'll come back soon.

Comment: Rewriting the MultiWordSuggestOracle class is working. Is there any way to add fixed header in suggestion popup?